# Estimating the residual variance by using a varFunc in nlme

Tags: r, residuals, lme4-nlme, generalized-least-squares

I'm using a linear model to predict a dependent variable (the score to a test) starting by the age of a person. As shown in the figure below, the variability decreases when the age increases (data are simulated!).

[image]

Since this characteristic trend of the variance, I'm using the Generalized Least Squares method implemented in R in the function gls() of the package nlme, by using the varExp variance function:

```
library("nlme")
vf <- varExp(form=~age)
fit <- gls(score~age, data=dataset, weights=vf)
```

The variance function provides a good distribution of residuals.

[image]

Now, I need to estimate, for some value of age, the corresponding value of the residual variance. However, the function predict() extracts only the fitted values, not the variances. There is a method to estimated the residual variance of each age, starting by the model?

Comment: see the `?varWeights` function, although I don't think it will predict for *new* values of age ...

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the help page for varExp, you can see that the function is defined as s2(v) = exp(2* t * v). Where t is the variance function coefficient and v is the covariate (in your case age).

`fit$modelStruct$varStruct`  should give you the parameter estimate for your variance coefficient. You can plot the variance against age by using `plot(y= exp( 2* fit$modelStruct$varStruct * dataset$age),x= dataset$age)`

Of course you can enter any value for age into `exp( 2* fit$modelStruct$varStruct * age)` to get a variance estimate for that particular age.
Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Dear Niek does your solution apply to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/494664/nlme-package-heterogenous-residual-variances-in-lme-in-r) as well?